# Handshake failure if URL path is specified

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm trying to use a REST API over HTTPS but I'm getting a handshake failure only if I specify an URL path (not getting the error with the domain name only).

Following the instructions of the API owner, I received a .PEM file (unsigned certificate?) with which I generated a CSR that I sent back, who in turn gave me back a private key file I then encapsulated with the certificate and the signing chain into a PFX file.

I imported the PFX into Internet Explorer certificate store, and I can now reach both the "root" URL (domain name only) ad the API URL (URL path included) without any problem. It is also working in Google Chrome and Postman.

Now, I'm trying to make it work with 3 other applications:

- CA Technologies - API Management
- Sofware AG - Integration Server
- Java 8 through HttpsURLConnection

In every case, I can reach the "root" URL and get a response but I'm getting a handshake failure if I add the path in the URL:

- Working : https://api.xxx.com/
- Not Working : https://api.xxx.com/method/

Let's take what  I did for each of my applications...

**1) CA Technologies - API Management**

I imported the PFX in the CA API Gateway with the "Manage Certifactes" import wizard. It added 3 certificate entries: the actual certificate, an intermediate certification authority and a root certification authority configured as a Trust Anchor. The certificate is checked to be used with "Outbound SSL Connections".

But when I use the assertion "Route via HTTPS" to my URL with the path, I get an handshake failure. I also tried to add a certificate to the store by using the "Manage Certificates" add wizard and giving it the URL with the path to download the certificate. It added 3 differents certificates in my store, but it still doesn't work.

**2) Software AG - Integration Server**

Since this ESB can't read PFX files, I exported the 3 certificates (actual + signing chain) to .CER files via Internet Explorer certificate export. In the WebMethods Integration Server Administrator console, I added the certificates with the "Configure Client Certificates" menu. I also configured the Keystore and the Truststore with their default values (DEFAULT_IS_KEYSTORE & DEFAULT_IS_TRUSTSTORE).

But using the service "pub.client:http" gave me the same error as precedently. I then tried to add my certificates directly inside the keystore of the embarked jvm (%SAG_PATH%/jvm/jvm/jre/lib/security), but it didn't solve the problem.

**3) Java 8 through HttpsURLConnection**

As a last resort, I tried to make it work directly in "pure" Java. I added the certifactes to my cacerts store and I created a class to connect to my URL and print informations :

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
System.out.println("\n");

Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
for (Certificate cert : certs) {
    System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
    System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : " + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : " + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

If I try to access the root URL I get a, OK response :

```
Response Code : 200
Cipher Suite : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : -952876714
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509

Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : 272760578
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509

Cert Type : X.509
Cert Hash Code : -1335658159
Cert Public Key Algorithm : RSA
Cert Public Key Format : X.509
```

But if I add the path to the actual API, I get an handshake failure too :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at test.Test.print_https_cert(Test.java:60)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

**Questions**

Do I need another certificate for the API actual URL (containing the full path)?
How can it work in my browser with the certificates but not in the other applications?
How do I correct the problem to make it work?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Following [@EnricoBasseti](https://serverfault.com/a/909989/467561) suggestions, I tried to enable/disabled (was disabled by default) the option "Follow Redirect" in CA API Gateway. It didn't change the error message.

I then tried to force Java to send SNI by modifiying my code :

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
SSLParameters sslParameters = new SSLParameters();
List<SNIServerName> sniHostNames = new ArrayList<>(1);
sniHostNames.add(new SNIHostName(url.getHost()));
sslParameters.setServerNames(sniHostNames);
SSLSocketFactory wrappedSSLSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactoryWrapper(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), sslParameters);
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(wrappedSSLSocketFactory);

HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But even with the SNI, I still get a Handshake failure if I use the full URL instead of only the domain name.

---

**EDIT 2**

With `-Djavax.net.debug.all`, I got more informations about the handshake failure :

```
verify_data:  { 216, 178, 49, 39, 2, 6, 100, 218, 54, 81, 137, 239 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C D8 B2 31 27   02 06 64 DA 36 51 89 EF  ......1'..d.6Q..
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C D8 B2 31 27   02 06 64 DA 36 51 89 EF  ......1'..d.6Q..
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
0000: 16 03 03 00 28 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 44 C8 8F  ....(........D..
0010: A5 85 F7 18 F4 14 E3 9F   79 C6 4C 7B E3 50 61 59  ........y.L..PaY
0020: B0 83 38 DA 16 91 49 41   76 B3 E0 CD 17           ..8...IAv....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 1A                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 26
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07   15 66 D8 8D F8 A5 88 D2  .........f......
0010: 44 24 BE 7B E4 1D 75 F7   58 C2                    D$....u.X.
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Not sure if this means I'm lacking a specific cipher or not.

---

**EDIT 3**

With the "root" URL, I get this log :

```
verify_data:  { 40, 57, 242, 4, 89, 211, 6, 190, 109, 98, 13, 50 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 28 39 F2 04   59 D3 06 BE 6D 62 0D 32  ....(9..Y...mb.2
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 28 39 F2 04   59 D3 06 BE 6D 62 0D 32  ....(9..Y...mb.2
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
0000: 16 03 03 00 28 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 5B 4A 01  ....(........[J.
0010: 6B 3B C3 43 29 8F EF CA   4B 85 85 93 BD 6C E3 9A  k;.C)...K....l..
0020: 2C D0 73 32 2A 33 1A 4A   5B 09 D1 A7 9C           ,.s2*3.J[....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 14 03 03 00 01                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 00 28                                     ....(
[Raw read]: length = 40
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   72 1F F6 DD 23 77 96 2D  ........r...#w.-
0010: DB BC 1E 10 CC 8A 64 6E   8B C1 A9 04 8A 08 62 20  ......dn......b 
0020: 2A 13 E3 DD 56 57 C3 AB                            *...VW..
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 6E 14 F6 CB   16 CA D8 B2 68 96 70 19  ....n.......h.p.
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 110, 20, 246, 203, 22, 202, 216, 178, 104, 150, 112, 25 }
***
%% Didn't cache non-resumable client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
[...] OMMITED (actual content of the URL) [...]
```

---

**EDIT 4**

Originally I couldn't import my PFX directly in my cacerts because I got the error `Illegal Key Size`. But since I configured "UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8", I was able to import it.

Then, following @dave_thompson_085 suggestions, I specified the keyStore to use in my Java code :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "XXXXX/jdk1.8.0_71/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "XXXXX");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "XXXXX/jdk1.8.0_71/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "XXXXX");
```

I first got the error `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` because I stored the key with a password different from the keystore's. But when I used the same password for the two elements, it worked correctly.

If I understand correctly, I was only sending the certificate but not my private key. I know have to find a way to do the same in CA API Gateway and Software AG Integration Server.

Comment: Your edit 2 omits most of the trace, but it does show the alert 40 is occurring at the end of the handshake. The most likely cause for this is that the server asked for client authentication, aka client certificate, and your system didn't provide it; that is also consistent with this occurring only on some URLs because some servers require client auth selectively per URL (but _can't_ vary SNI per URL). If you look earlier in the trace you should see that the server sent 'Certificate Request' and your system responded with an _empty_ 'Certificate' message. ...

Comment: ... For your #4, confirm you have the cert chain _and private key_ (NOT just the certs) in _one_ privateKeyEntry in the keystore, and specify it with the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` properties or by loading the keystore and using it to initialize your SSLContext. JRE/lib/security/cacerts is used as default for _truststore_, but NOT keystore.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You were a 100% right. I added my private key to the keystore and forced my Java client to use it, and it worked! I updated my post. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@dave_thompson_085](https://serverfault.com/users/216633/dave-thompson-085) and [@EnricoBasseti](https://serverfault.com/users/467519/enrico-bassetti), I managed to make it work with my 3 applications.

Here's what I did for each one:

**1) CA Technologies - API Management**

In the "Manage Private Key" Import wizard, I added the key from the PFX file. Then in the "Manage Certificate" Add wizard, I imported the certificate from the Private Key's Certificate Chain (4th option). I then used the "Manage Certificate" Add wizard to import the certificate from the API URL (different certificate in my case).

Then in my policy, I right clicked on my "Route to HTTP(S) assertion" and clicked on "Select Private Key" to force CA API Gateway to use the private key I imported precedently instead of its default one.

**2) Software AG - Integration Server**

In myWebmethod Web Console, in "Security" and "Keystore", I clicked on "Create Keystore Alias". I configured a new PCKS12 keystore and gave it my PFX file (had to specify both the keystore password and the key password separately).

Then in "Security" and "Certificates", I clicked on "Configure Client Certificates" and added the Root Certificate from my certification chain (I had previously exported with IE). I also added the Root Certificate from the URL certification chain (different in my case).

Finally in my Flow Service, before using the "pub.client:http" component, I added a "pub.security.keystore:setKeyAndChain" component configured to use my new KeyStore alias and its Key alias.

**3) Java 8 through HttpsURLConnection**

I had to replace my JDK security policy files by those provided by oracle: [UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) (only if using JDK8 < 161). Then I imported the Key Pair in my cacerts file (%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts). I also imported the Root Certificate of the API URL (which is different from the one contained in my PFX file).

Then in my code, I forced Java to use my cacerts as a KeyStore (see EDIT 4 from my original post).

Answer (score 0):

The TLS connection is established before the HTTP request, so there is no way to distinguish (on the server side) which endpoint you'll request (only the hostname using SNI). This is why certificates doesn't include the full URL.

So, crashing on the handshake for different URL is very strange - maybe the endpoint URL is doing a `302` redirect to another server? See if the application that you're using have options to disable the option `Follow HTTP redirects` (or something like that).

You can also use Internet Explorer to check this: see if the URL changes when you try to reach `https://api.xxx.com/method/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to check with IE, but since the API returns JSON, IE doesn't access the page to display the URL but instead asks me if I want to save the JSON file. I tried in Google Chrome, and the URL displayed in the navigation bar was the same as the one I tried to access. With the Developper Tools, in the Network Tab, I get a 200 response but not a 301 or 302. I'm investigating my applications to try to disable Follow HTTP redirects.

Comment: Also check if both apps and java code are sending the SNI component when making a TLS connection

Comment: I tried to enable/disable "Follow redirect" and I forced Java to send SNI, but both didn't change the error message. See my edit to original post. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you ever used Wireshark? If so, you can trace the TLS handshake and see if the connection is truncated at the handshake (I begin to think that the message "handshake failure" is somehow wrong or incorrect.

Comment: I configured my Java program with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to see more about the handshake. I updated my post with the logs. I don't know how to use Wireshark.

Comment: Maybe you can add the cryptography extensions to enable ciphers that are marked as "unavailable": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Can you make the same trace for the working URL? Thanks :-)

Comment: With "UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8", I still get the handshake error, but the messages about unavailable ciphers disappear. I added the logs for the working URL.

Comment: @EnricoBassetti: the trace shows the server already agreed to an AES-128 suite, so the unlimited _policy_ files (which are NOT themselves JCE or 'extensions') are not needed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 sorry I missed that